# Facebook feeds on website

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get some fb feeds on a website. I've searched the web and found a couple things I could try. After failing quite a bit, I've managed to get it. Today the access token wasn't valid anymore, so I got a new one and it worked again. After a bit (token still valid) it didn't anymore (got two messages). So I searched again and found a new solution that works and I think that gives me a token which is longer valid. This is the php code:

```
<?php
$limit = 3;
$profile_id = "32796xxxxx64243";
//App Info, needed for Auth
$app_id = "59351xxxxx41974";
$app_secret = "082d36fe4108ae51xxxxxxxxxxfb84b4";
//retrieve a new Auth token
$curl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='.$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret;
//$authToken = file_get_contents($curl);
$authToken = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?{$authToken}");
echo $data;
?>
```

This gives me following result:
[image]

Now I'm trying to get all the info out of it, but here is where I'm getting an error in my foreach loop. This is the code I use:

```
<div id="footer">
    <h5>Laatste Facebook feeds</h5>
    <div class="wrapperfb">
        <?
            $counter = 0; 
            foreach($data->data as $d){
            if($counter==$limit)
            break;   

        ?>
        <div class="singlefb">
            <div class="imgfb">
                <a class="afb" href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$d->from->id?>">
                <img border="0" alt="<?=$d->from->name?>" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$d->from->id?>/picture"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="textfb">
                <span style="font-weight:bold"><a class="afb" href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$d->from->id?>">
                <?=$d->from->name?></a></span><br/>
                    <span style="color: #999999;">on <?=date('F j, Y H:i',strtotime($d->created_time))?></span>
                    <br/>
                <?=$d->message?>
            </div>
       </div>
        <?
            $counter++;
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /customers/9/2/3/beach-korfbal.be/httpd.www/facebookFeeds.php on line
>   19

line 19 is the foreach loop:

> foreach($data->data as $d){

It's probably something stupid I'm looking over. Could someone please help me out. This is the last thing I need to complete to launch the site.

Comment: You need to do json_decode() your returned JSON data. You can make it an array and then loop through as $data = json_decode($data,true).

Comment: I've tried that before a couple times, but didn't work (because I put it in the wrong place). Now it works. I added it only to $data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now thanks to Abhik Chakraborty's comment.

This is the full code:

```
<?php
$limit = 5;
$profile_id = "32796xxxxx64243";
//App Info, needed for Auth
$app_id = "59351xxxxx41974";
$app_secret = "082d36fe4108ae51xxxxxxxxxxfb84b4";
//retrieve a new Auth token
$authToken = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?{$authToken}"));
?>
<div id="footer">
    <h5>Laatste Facebook feeds</h5>
    <div class="wrapperfb">
        <?
            $counter = 0; 
            foreach($data->data as $d){
            if($counter==$limit)
            break;   

        ?>
        <div class="singlefb">
            <div class="imgfb">
                <a class="afb" href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$d->from->id?>">
                <img border="0" alt="<?=$d->from->name?>" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$d->from->id?>/picture"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="textfb">
                <span style="font-weight:bold"><a class="afb" href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$d->from->id?>">
                <?=$d->from->name?></a></span><br/>
                    <span style="color: #999999;">on <?=date('F j, Y H:i',strtotime($d->created_time))?></span>
                    <br/>
                <?=$d->message?>
            </div>
       </div>
        <?
            $counter++;
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```